# UFT: Unable to identify Object's parent window though it is being added in Object Repository

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft, wp-calypso

I'm working on Calypso windows application where I have to click on a tab within a window. When I was executing the script, I see error message saying that "Cannot find the object's parent window" . I have verified that window properties don't change and no other window is opened with same title.

Please suggest how I can click the tab in the window.

```
call JavaWindow("Back Office Window for").Activate
JavaWindow("Back Office Window for").JavaTab("Pay Role").Select ("Postings")
```

THE Window Title is dynamic and keeps changing as shown below

```
Back Office Window for Trade 4562213 (User: polaris_bouser1)
```

[image: Window is displayed and need to click Postings tab.]

[image: Object Repository]

Comment: Have you added regular expression for any of the properties listed in your last screenshot?

Comment: I suppose the dynamic title has a trade ID which should be unique and dynamic for each trade, have you taken care of that?

Comment: @MithileshIndurkar I tried something like shown below and even that didn't work.

Comment: JavaWindow("title:=Back Office Window for Trade \D (User: )").Activate

Comment: Try JavaWindow("title:=Back Office Window for Trade.*").Activate.... If this helps, use the same statement in your object repository, using the button next to the property . check the regular expression checkbox.... use this link to quickly go through how to use regular expression

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdIBhl0p6Fo

Comment: Ok let me try this .

Comment: @MithileshIndurkar It worked :-) Thanks a ton!!

Comment: Posting this as an answer, please do accept the same as a token of appreciation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
JavaWindow("title:=Back Office Window for Trade.*").Activate
```

If this helps, use the same statement in your object repository, using the button next to the property . check the regular expression checkbox.... use this link to quickly go through how to use regular expression [youtube.com/watch?v=IdIBhl0p6Fo](http://youtube.com/watch?v=IdIBhl0p6Fo) –